# How to change xlib coordinates origin

Tags: c++, xlib

I'm implementing x windows system in my own render. The problem is that x window's coordinates start at top-left corner, but my calculations are based on bottom-left corner coordinates origin. So how can I invert x window coordinates to bootom-left and if I cant't do that how do I convert my coordinates to x window coordinates.

P.S. I know there is `xrandr -o normal|inverted|left|right` command, so I'm wondering if I can use it in my code to invert my window.